# Which public-key algorithm is suitable for videos and images?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I am planning to create an application that has to be able to securely (that is, encrypted) send messages between clients. These messages may include images and videos (up to 50MB in size). Due to how public-key cryptography works, the encryption process has to be run once for each public key.
For these reasons, I am looking for an algorithm that can encrypt the media fairly quickly on modern devices (eg. mid-level smartphones).

I am asking the question because all algorithms I came across (Blowfish and RSA for example) have a relatively small payload limit, which means that even an image will not fit into it.

Comment: Blowfish is a secret-key (symmetric) cipher not a public-key (asymmetric) one; like all block symmetric ciphers it is used in various [modes of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) which have different limits on size. In particular CBC, CFB and OFB become unsafe around the birthday bound which for Blowfish's 8-byte block is 32GiB, realistic for modern video data. But if you want a symmetric cipher that isn't AES/Rijndael, Twofish or one of the other nonwinning AES finalists like Serpent or RC6 would be safer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about the input size for `RSA`. In general, for any public key cryptography, the input size of limited and as opposed to your needs, it's quite a bit slower than what you need. Public key cryptography is usually used to share small pieces of data.

For example, in the TLS implementation using RSA (`TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256`), the RSA step is used to share a symmetric key, generally, AES, between 2 parties and then all the heavy lifting is done by AES.

What you need is a [symmetric encryption algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm). You can use [`AES`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) (key sizes of 128, 192 or even 256) to encrypt your images which can be of any size. AES is a [block cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher) and, using a suitable [block cipher mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation), theoretically does not have an input limit to it. AES-128 is a fairly standard NIST approved (FIPS 197) symmetric encryption scheme, so it should be safe, but you can always go for a higher key size, say 256.

Since, you have the security of the algorithm defined, we can now talk about the speed. 
RSA:

```
$ openssl speed rsa2048
Doing 2048 bit private rsa's for 10s: 296 2048 bit private RSA's in 10.00s
Doing 2048 bit public rsa's for 10s: 6171 2048 bit public RSA's in 9.99s
LibreSSL 2.6.5
built on: date not available
options:bn(64,64) rc4(ptr,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) aes(partial) blowfish(idx)
compiler: information not available
                  sign    verify    sign/s verify/s
rsa 2048 bits 0.033784s 0.001619s     29.6    617.7
```

AES-128 in GCM mode

```
$ openssl speed aes-128-gcm
Doing aes-128 gcm for 3s on 16 size blocks: 3778792 aes-128 gcm's in 2.99s
Doing aes-128 gcm for 3s on 64 size blocks: 1611239 aes-128 gcm's in 3.00s
Doing aes-128 gcm for 3s on 256 size blocks: 485243 aes-128 gcm's in 2.99s
Doing aes-128 gcm for 3s on 1024 size blocks: 125054 aes-128 gcm's in 2.99s
Doing aes-128 gcm for 3s on 8192 size blocks: 15366 aes-128 gcm's in 2.96s
LibreSSL 2.6.5
built on: date not available
options:bn(64,64) rc4(ptr,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) aes(partial) blowfish(idx)
compiler: information not available
The 'numbers' are in 1000s of bytes per second processed.
type             16 bytes     64 bytes    256 bytes   1024 bytes   8192 bytes
aes-128 gcm      20220.96k    34373.10k    41545.89k    42827.86k    42526.44k
```

You can see the difference, how AES can blow away RSA in the dust with respect to speed. Symmetric Encryption algorithms are inherently faster due to its design. Asymmetric algorithms use math operations on huge numbers and primes which are slower.

Since AES is so popular, CPU manufacturers started implementing special instructions to make AES computations more and more native ([AES-NI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set)). So AES will be faster on almost all popular CPUs.

A small note on security between RSA and AES, although it's like comparing apples to oranges.
RSA2048 offers only 112 bits of security whereas AES128 offers 128 bits of security (ref: [aes-vs-rsa](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/47991/aes-vs-rsa-which-is-stronger-given-two-scenarios/47993))

Another challenge in the above problem would be key management. How would you safely manage the keys? If the keys are to be ephemeral, i.e. session based or one key per use, then you can use RSA to exchange symmetric keys and then perform the encryption. This would guarantee perfect forward secrecy. If you want persistent keys, then obviously there are much more elaborate methods to do that which is out of scope of this question.

Comment: Sharing the AES key via RSA is a very creative way. Thank you for your help

Comment: @DaniFoldi, For sharing the AES keys using RSA, no thanks to me, it's actually used in the TLS handshake, one of the schemes that uses it is `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256`, as mentioned in the answer. I am assuming that you explicitly need to encrypt the data over TLS, as TLS is already encrypting your data using AES. I like @Gilles's answer too, which would be my recommendation to, don't implement your own crypto, but given my assumption that you have a requirement, here we are. It's a very standard practice to encrypt large amounts of data using a Symmetric Encryption Algorithm.

Comment: you are right, my app has to use an encryption that can't be decrypted on the server, only on clients

Answer (score 4):

[Don't roll your own protocol](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own). You're thinking about this [at a far too low level](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2009/july/if-youre-typing-the-letters-a-e-s-into-your-code-youre-doing-it-wrong/). People who know exactly what they're doing have a hard time writing secure code. You don't even know where to start, so you don't stand a chance of getting it right.

If you can establish a direct connection between the two endpoints, **use [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)**. If you can't establish a direct connection, consider using TLS and relaying the encrypted packets; if that's impractical, [use Signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_Protocol). TLS is ubiquitous; your operating system(s) probably come with an implementation in their default installation. Signal is less ubiquitous, so you'll probably have to embed a library. Make sure to keep up with updates to this library. And once again, don't implement your own library.

---

Under the hood, all systems that use public-key cryptography to store or transmit more than a few bytes of data use [hybrid cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem). Public-key cryptography is used to establish a symmetric key and authenticate the data, and symmetric cryptography does the heavy lifting.

For example, RSA can be used to encrypt a symmetric key. It's pretty difficult to get it right in practice, however. It's also slower than more modern methods that use elliptic-curve cryptography. TLS can use RSA encryption, but this is deprecated. TLS preferably uses an ([elliptic curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman)) [Diffie-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) [key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key-agreement_protocol) and an RSA or [(EC)DSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm) [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature) to set up the secure connection. If you'd like more explanations about how TLS works, read [an overview of the protocol](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work/20847#20847), [a history of problems and how they were resolved](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work/20851#20851), and [an explanation of why RSA encryption is problematic](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/205639/how-does-tls-work-rsa-diffie-hellman-pfs/205689#205689).

Note that Blowfish has been obsolete for a while. If you ever need to choose a specific symmetric cryptosystem — [which usually means you're doing it wrong](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2009/july/if-youre-typing-the-letters-a-e-s-into-your-code-youre-doing-it-wrong/) — pick AES-GCM, AES-CCM or ChaCha20-Poly1305.